# No space after the word when I defined a macro, bug?

Tags: macros, formatting

I defined a macro but I found the word spacing is gone. Am I missing something?

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}

\newcommand{\abc}{$abc$}
\newcommand{\abcSpace}{$abc$ }

\begin{document}

Word spacing here $abc$ is correct.

Word spacing here \abc is incorrect.

Why do I need to define macro like this \abcSpace in order to have a space?

But within brackets, this space again is not what I want: (\abcSpace).


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfectly normal and documented behavior. Use `\abc\ is` when you want a space.

Comment: Why tex is designed in this way, I thought macro is just replacement. Sadly, it is not.

Comment: I'd be sad if this weren't documented. It is; spaces after control sequences consisting of letters (like your `\abc`) are ignored. That's the way it is.

Comment: Consider using `xspace` which adds space automatically whenever necessary.

Comment: Why downvote?  Even if a duplicate question, it is a common one, and there is a minimal example. (If only all people included them in their questions!) Is the downvote meant to imply 'look harder before asking'?

Comment: Thanks for your understanding @jon! And sometime, it is just difficult to choose keywords to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use macro with `{}` solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}

\newcommand{\abc}{$abc$}

\begin{document}

Word spacing \abc{} is correct now.

Within brackets: (\abc{}).

\end{document}
```